# TSQL - Return recent date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Having issues getting a dataset to return with one date per client in the query.

Requirements:

- Must have the recent date of transaction per client list for user
- Will need have the capability to run through EXEC

Current Query:

```
SELECT
    c.client_uno
    , c.client_code
    , c.client_name
    , c.open_date
into #AttyClnt
from hbm_client c
    join hbm_persnl p on c.resp_empl_uno = p.empl_uno
where p.login = @login
    and c.status_code = 'C'

select
    ba.payr_client_uno as client_uno
    , max(ba.tran_date) as tran_date
from blt_bill_amt ba
    left outer join #AttyClnt ac on ba.payr_client_uno = ac.client_uno
where ba.tran_type IN ('RA', 'CR')
group by ba.payr_client_uno
```

Currently, this query will produce at least 1 row per client with a date, the problem is that there are some clients that will have between 2 and 10 dates associated with them bloating the return table to about 30,000 row instead of an idealistic 246 rows or less.

When i try doing max(tran_uno) to get the most recent transaction number, i get the same result, some have 1 value and others have multiple values.

The bigger picture has 4 other queries being performed doing other parts, i have only included the parts that pertain to the question.

**Edit (2011-10-14 @ 1:45PM):**

```
    select 
    ba.payr_client_uno as client_uno
    , max(ba.row_uno) as row_uno
into #Bills
from blt_bill_amt ba
    inner join hbm_matter m on ba.matter_uno = m.matter_uno
        inner join hbm_client c on m.client_uno = c.client_uno
            inner join hbm_persnl p on c.resp_empl_uno = p.empl_uno
where p.login = @login
    and c.status_code = 'C'
    and ba.tran_type in ('CR', 'RA')
group by ba.payr_client_uno
order by ba.payr_client_uno

--Obtain list of Transaction Date and Amount for the Transaction
select
    b.client_uno
    , ba.tran_date
    , ba.tc_total_amt
from blt_bill_amt ba
    inner join #Bills b on ba.row_uno = b.row_uno
```

Not quite sure what was going on but seems the Temp Tables were not acting right at all.  Ideally i would have 246 rows of data, but with the previous query syntax it would produce from 400-5000 rows of data, obviously duplications on data.

Comment: I don't think the problem is here.  What you're showing there will only return one date per client_uno, since you're grouping by that value.  Could there be whitespace in the client name that makes it seem like the same client is returning multiple dates?

Comment: the client_uno is a unique 'int' value and therefore has no white space or errorneous values.  the value is controlled on the back end of the application.

Comment: Another note, in some instances when looking at the resulting data-set, some client_uno have a CR & RA record and some others have a double CR or RA record, and the rest are either single CR or RA value.  Now you see the problem, its not consistently return a value back that i can peg the problem to.  More of a culmination of problems that are not very consistent except by the client_uno that i query against.

Comment: The select statement that you show here will only return one record per client_uno.  If there's a different query that you're working with that is returning the duplicates, please show that one...

Comment: You would think....but there were 4 rows that returned 2 dates....and they were totally different dates.

Comment: @GoldBishop - I'm an ex ADERANT developer, feel free to ping me (address in profile) if you have more questions on the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use ranking to achieve what you want:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    client_uno = ba.payr_client_uno,
    ba.tran_date,
    be.tc_total_amt,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ba.payr_client_uno
      ORDER BY     ba.tran_uno DESC
    )
  FROM blt_bill_amt ba
    INNER JOIN hbm_matter m ON ba.matter_uno = m.matter_uno
    INNER JOIN hbm_client c ON m.client_uno = c.client_uno
    INNER JOIN hbm_persnl p ON c.resp_empl_uno = p.empl_uno
  WHERE p.login = @login
    AND c.status_code = 'C'
    AND ba.tran_type IN ('CR', 'RA')
)
SELECT
  client_uno,
  tran_date,
  tc_total_amt
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY client_uno
```

Useful reading:

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

  - [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

  - [Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try this when get back to the client....didnt know there was a ranking mechanism for SQL 2005

Comment: Bravo Andriy....it tentatively works....waiting on verification.  And thank you for the links....im going to read up on those articles for further reading.

Comment: Andriy....why would i get this message "Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 70 'mattranked' is not a recognized GROUP BY option." After dumping the Select statement into a temp table of its own....added 'Into #LastPay'.  Or is this something i am unable to do and i should do the join at the final query?

Comment: got it answered from the MS Bug report system....refer to [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288760/group-by-bug-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @GoldBishop: I couldn't see your question before you posted the link. Not sure if I would have been able to answer the question correctly, but now that I've read the bug report I can see what was happening. A missing semicolon before `WITH` (in the context of defining a CTE) is not uncommon mistake. I myself have been bitten by it more than once.